# How to send an email in Logic App with from address set to no-reply?

Tags: azure, email, azure-logic-apps

I'm  looking for a way to  send email  notification to a group from LogicApps.
I could see that the monitoring in Azure sends email from:no-reply@microsoft.com.

Can anyone help me in achieving this from  logic app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few connectors in Logic apps which allow you to send emails. They are 
1) O365 connector
2) Gmail connector
3) Send Grid

Among these three the first two work with a particular mail id which you use to create a connection to the office 365 and gmail. SO when you want to send the emails from these connectors, they will pick up by default the user with which connection to them was created. BUT you can circumvent this behavior. Refer following screenshot

For Office 365

[image: Send As different user]

But please understand that it requires a valid email address and it requires the current user used to create in logic apps to have necessary and sufficient permissions on the send as user.

For GMAIL

It is not possible to set a FROM field in the GMAIL connector

In case of send grid you have the option to set the 'From' email address, BUT the requirement is that "***It needs to be a valid email in your organizations domain***". Refer the official documentation for the Send Grid Connector.
[Send Grid Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sendgrid/#send-email-(v4))

And I would suggest you to create your own no-reply email id rather than using microsoft's .

Comment: Thanks!But let me try to emphasize the solution I'm looking.We have an existing setup wherein azure  email alerts are being sent to interested receipients which originates from no-reply@microsoft.com.Therefore,the email from Logic App too has to originate from the same mail id (no-reply@microsoft.com).

Comment: Ok, but as I mentioned earlier, you need to give proper permissions to be able to send the email from an microsoft email id, which is not possible for custom flows. 
The "no-reply@microsoft.com" is an email id owned and used by Microsoft to send notifications. Now since the monitoring of the logic apps is a basic part of the PAAS offering from microsoft, they send out emails using those ids. But the emails that you want to send from the Logic apps are you custom alerts generated by you and hence should ideally use a no reply id from your org.

Comment: Thanks for detailing it.Makes sense!

Comment: if your question was answered, could you please mark the answer.